# Rails Delayed Job production not picking up change in class/job code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, delayed-job, worker

I am running a stack of nginx, passenger, rails, delayed_job gem which is running an import.rake task from lib/tasks/ on Ubuntu LTS.

If I make a code change on production to import.rake.

I do a

```
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job stop
touch tmp/restart.txt
ps aux | egrep '(PID|nginx)'
sudo kill -HUP [PID]
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start
```

However, it still does not recognize my change of import.rake. I'm at a loss of what to do. Maybe there is something i'm not thinking of?

I've ran

```
ps -ef | grep delayed_job
```

to see if there are any lingering jobs and after running the delayed_job stop command from above all i see is

```
[server_name] 9426  6168  0 18:46 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto delayed_job
```

which shouldn't be an issue. I've also tried just rebooting the server which didn't help.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are your delayed jobs failing or just not being run at all? It might be helpful to inspect one of these jobs in question and look at how it has been serialized. Look at the value of the handler column in the delayed_jobs table. Is it directly calling something in your import.rake?

Answer (score 2):

Delayed job serializes the *instance* of your code when it enqueues it, so redeployment won't help unless you change the code that is invoked *by* your rake task, rather than the rake task itself.

To solve this, decouple the code you change between redeployments from the code that is invoked via delayed job. So, instead of `MyLogic.delay.do_stuff`, you could do this:

```
class DelayedTask
  def self.do_stuff
    self.new.delay.execute
  end

  private 

  def execute
    MyLogic.do_stuff
  end
end
```

Then just call `DelayedTask.do_stuff` from your code, and you can change `MyLogic.do_stuff` in any way you want (without changing the method name or params), ant it will work.

Comment: Currently, my rake task contains a bunch of code that goes through albums and does some image processing and things. What you are saying is I can move that code into the do_stuff method instead of having the import.rake script. Correct?

Comment: Yes, rake task should merely invoke your business logic code. And if you decouple delaying of the task away from business logic, pending delayed_job tasks will less likely break when you change something.